# Create new instance of JLabel each time it is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a `JPanel` with a `JLabel` in it, is it possible to have a mouse click on `JLabel`, following by another mouse click on any location on the `JPanel` to create an instance of the `JLabel`. Basically, I can click the `JLabel` and create new instances of it anywhere on the `JPanel`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If the question is "is it possible?" then yes.

Comment: Any idea how I could go about creating that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what you are looking for. What you need is `deepCopy` of the clicked `JLabel` and then retrieve it back and draw it to the `JPanel`.
[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
class CopyLabel extends JFrame
{

    JPanel panel ;
    JPanel centerPanel;
    int clickCount = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    ByteArrayInputStream bins;
    public void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        setTitle("Copy JLabel");
        JLabel label1  = new JLabel("JLabel1");
        JLabel label2  = new JLabel("JLabel2");
        panel = new JPanel();
        label1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);
        class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                clickCount = 1;
                try
                {
                    deepCopy((JLabel)evt.getSource());
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
        label1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        label2.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Controllers"));
        getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(),"Drawing Pad",TitledBorder.CENTER,TitledBorder.TOP));
        centerPanel.setLayout(null);
        centerPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                if (clickCount == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        pasteLabel(evt.getX(),evt.getY());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){}
                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
        setSize(300,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void deepCopy(JLabel label)throws Exception
    {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(label);
        oos.close();
    }
    public void pasteLabel(int x, int y)throws Exception
    {
        if (clickCount == 1)
        {
            bins = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream oins = new ObjectInputStream(bins);
            JLabel obj = (JLabel)oins.readObject();
            centerPanel.add(obj);
            obj.setBounds(x,y,obj.getWidth(),obj.getHeight());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                CopyLabel cl = new CopyLabel();
                cl.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped! If I want the JLabel in the Drawing pad to be movable, what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach mouse listener to your JLabel like this

```
   final JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("Test");
    jlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hello : "+ e);
            Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            targetPanel.add(cloneLabelAt(jlabel, location)); 
        }
    });


private JLabel cloneLabelAt(JLabel label, Point location)
{
    JLabel cloned  = new JLabel(label.getText());
    cloned.setLocation(location);
    return cloned;
}
```

Inside your mouse click handler you can create another JLabel and add it to your target panel

Comment: While technique correct, two things jump out at me, 1- there's no need to call super, as the MouseAdapter creates empty implementations of the methods from MouseListener and MouseMotionListener (no big deal), 2- To really answer the question, you would need the ability to clone a object that was clicked on and the place the cloned reference onto the target container (as I read it, at the same location as the second click). The question may not be about mouse listeners, but that's just my tame in it

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have the cloned reference at the location of the second mouse-click, how can that be done?

Comment: you can use MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()

Comment: Hi Greg, could you provide an example for that? Kind of confused right now

Comment: It seems like it duplicates the JLabel each time it is clicked, how can it be done such that the first click is only selecting that particular JLabel and the second click is to paste the JLabel at exact location of the second click